# Get all child elements by its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the div structure.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
  <input type="text" id="tf1">
  <input type="text" id="tf2">
  <input type="text" id="tf3">
  <button id="bt3">Text</button>
</div>
```

I use the below code by specifying individual IDs.

**EDIT**

There is a `$(document).click` set and I am avoiding a function being triggered if the user is currently typing anything into any of these text fields. All works okay. My question is instead of adding separate elements as the target is there a way to include all elements within the parent?

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#tf1, #tf2, #tf3, #btn3").length) { //Can these  individual elements be replaced by using parent div ID?
      return;
    }

    if (typeof commonFunc == "function"){ 
        commonFunc();
    }  
});
```

By doing this I do not need to have track of new elements being added.

Comment: Do you mean something like `$(e.target).children()`?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement clearly?

Comment: Which means what is your present state and what is your expected output?

Comment: Is this what you want: $(e.target).closest("#parentDiv").children().length ?

Comment: `.closest()` goes *up* the DOM tree (it's similar to `.parent()`) - to go *down* to get child elements, simply change to `.children()` - no arguments means all, or add arguments to filter.

Comment: @JodiSupporter spot on!! thanks. Please add your answer. I'll accept.

Comment: @Fergoso Glad I helped! I added my asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

```
if($(e.target).closest("#parentDiv").children().length)
```

Comment: Why you are checking for `children` length here, while you taking `closest`    element of that `children`? Finding any `closest("#parentDiv")` mean it must has children.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(e.target).children() // Will return all the children of whatever e.target is
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).children().length==0) {
      // No children element.
      return;
    }
    else{
      // There are some child elements.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using it in an `$(document).click()` function. How should `$('#parentDiv').children()` be added?

Comment: See my edit. I want all elements within `$('#parentDiv')` to be included instead of having to type all elements within separately. e.g. `.closest("#tf1, #tf2, #tf3, #btn3").length`

Comment: See my edited answer. If it helps please considering upvoting and marking it as correct answerr.

Comment: `$("#parentDiv").children().length`